# How to import gRPC empty and Google api annotations proto

Tags: google-cloud-platform, protocol-buffers, google-cloud-endpoints, grpc, protoc

I am trying to use Google Cloud Endpoints to make a gRPC based api that can [transcode incoming REST requests](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/transcoding). I am following [their example code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/endpoints/bookstore-grpc/http_bookstore.proto) but I can not any documentation on how to properly import and compile with the annotation.proto or the empty.proto.

Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I didn't understand that this was part of grpc-gateway. By [following the docs](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway) I ran

```
protoc -I/usr/local/include -I. -I$GOPATH/src -I$GOPATH/src/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/third_party/googleapis --go_out=plugins=grpc:. *.proto
```

and compiled successfully.

Answer (score 8):

it may not be a good idea.
you can copy `google/api/annotations.proto` and `google/api/http.proto` into your local project and import them when run `python -m`

```
mkdir -p google/api    
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googleapis/googleapis/master/google/api/annotations.proto > google/api/annotations.proto     
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googleapis/googleapis/master/google/api/http.proto > google/api/http.proto

python -m grpc_tools.protoc google/api/http.proto google/api/annotations.proto -I. --python_out=. --grpc_python_out=. your_proto.proto
```

refurl: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/exposing-grpc-services-using-cloud-endpoints-pt1

Comment: It's not working for me. I have grpcio and grpcio-tools. On adding the two files, I get the error "google.protobuf.MethodOptions" is not defined (in annotations.proto). How to get past this?

Answer (score 5):

The empty.proto and annotation.proto are not included by default, so you'll need to bring in a copy.  Specifically you can make a copy of them in a directory in your project, or reference them in an existing project (like the Protobuf git repo, for instance).

It is probably a good idea to *NOT* reference the copy that grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway uses, because they may want to move it around in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Using `go list -m -f '{{.Dir}}'` helps better resolve `go mod` dependencies when installed under `$GOPATH/pkg/mod`.

```
grpc_ecosystem_path=`go list -m -f '{{.Dir}}' github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway`

protoc \
    --proto_path="$grpc_ecosystem_path/third_party/googleapis" \
# ...
```